# My JUnit tests don't work when I execute them via maven

Tags: java, junit

I use Maven on my test project and I wanted to test `test` option in Maven's lifecycle, but my JUnit test failed. I have a class named `Arithmetics` in `src.main.java` package and a class named `ArithmeticsTest` in `src.test.java` package.

When I run `ArithmeticsTest` on my own using IntelliJ IDEA everything works OK, and I have expected `java.lang.AssertionError`, so why I don't have such when I run test option in maven?

Console output:

> ---
>
> ### T E S T S
>
> Results :
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

src.main.java.Arithmetics.java

```
public class Arithmetics
{
    public static int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

src.test.java.ArithmeticsTest.java

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class ArithmeticsTest
{
    @Test
    public void testAdd()
    {
        assertEquals(4, Arithmetics.add(2, 3));
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

Comment: Why do you have `junit-jupiter` dependency twice with different scope?

Comment: @code_mechanic just to make it wok... but it doesn't work with either scope

Comment: @Stultuske i think OP wants to know why the test is not failing.

Comment: What's the structure of your project? And why in the console it says ` Running ArithmeticsTest Configuring TestNG` ?

Comment: Did you add this question again?

Comment: @code_mechanic yes, and previous question was solved, but I changed JUnit4 to Junit5 and it doesn't work again

Comment: @Davide it's mistaken output, I updated it now

Comment: I think, you have repeated the same mistakes as you did with earlier question, check if below answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answer already pointed out few things which may go wrong in your case, I am just adding the solution to your pom xml.

The surefire plugin version is the main culprit. Default with maven (2.12.4) will not work with junit-5 jupiter engine.

So just add the plugin in your with version `2.22.1` in your pom, it should work after that, assuming your folder structure as per required (see other answer).

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are three wrong things I can spot based on your question, while they might not provide a complete answer I hope they'll will be a step in a right direction:

1. `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` is not a package as you write. Its a folder layout supported by maven, basically , if you have a code in `com.myorg.somepackage.Arithmetics`
   Make sure you have the following layout at the level of actual physical folders:

```
src
 main
  java
    com
     myorg
       somepackage
         Arithmetics.java
 test
  java
    com
     myorg
       somepackage
         ArithmeticsTest.java
```

For both java files the package must be `com.myorg.somepackage`:

```
package com.myorg.somepackage;

public class Arithmetics {}
```

And

```
package com.myorg.somepackage;

public class ArithmeticsTest {}
```

I know it might be a wrong naming that you've used in the question, but still I have to state it because it might cause an actual issue

2. The second issue is that for some reason you seem to configure your surefire plugin to use test ng which is an alternative to junit. It can happen because testng is placed as a dependency - I can only speculate because you don't really show the full surefire plugin configure and do not provide a full list of dependencies, but you've got and idea I believe :)

This is wrong because you use the junit5 dependencies as well as the imports that correspond to the junit 5.

3. The dependencies on the junit 5 are completely messy:

You seem to have two dependencies on just the same with the different scope, its really a wrong thing to do. Make sure you use only the `test` scope and have all the relevant dependencies. Read [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html) for instruction of how to configure the surefire plugin

In addition, for the sake of completeness of the answer, check that you use the recent version of surefire plugin, if its too old the chances are that it won't be able to run jupiter engine (junit 5)

Comment: It's all my dependencies cause it's test projects just to learn junit. I use surefire plugin version 2.12.4